# Modal pop up working fine in IE7 but not in IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, panel, modalpopupextender

I have a panel which I am showing on button click (modal pop up extender). Now, that panel is showing correctly in IE7 but shrink in IE8. It shrink so much that items in it got overlapped.

Here is the panel code:

```
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlGallery" runat="server">
        <div id="divGallery" class="gallery">
            <ul>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DataList ID="ddlgal" RepeatColumns="5" runat="server" GridLines="None"
                                OnItemDataBound="ddlgal_ItemDataBound">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <li>
```

Please let me know if more code is required.

Comment: Oh ! I have done with setting min-width. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake for other developers who encounter the same problem,

I have set the min-width property to appropriate level and it worked fine in both IE7 and IE8.